# SELinux is not enabled

Tags: selinux

I installed SELINUX on ubuntu using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install selinux
```

config file in `/etc/selinux` contain following information

```
SELINUX=permissive

SELINUXTYPE=default

SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

But i am not able to set selinux, when I check using `sestatus -v command`
it gives output

```
SELINUX is disabled
```

How should I enable my SELINUX?

When I use command `seinfo`. it gives following output

```
ERROR: policydb version 26 does not match my version range 15-24
ERROR: Unable to open policy /etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.26.
ERROR: Input/output error
```

check-selinux-installation command gives following output 
../proc/1   kernel..

SELinux is not enabled. The init process (PID 1) is running in an incorrect domain. /etc/pam.d/login is not SELinux enabled 
FSCKFIX is not enabled - not serious, but could prevent system from booting... 
udev will create nodes not labeled correctly

Please help

Comment: check-selinux-installation command gives following output
../proc/1 kernel..
SELinux is not enabled.
The init process (PID 1) is running in an incorrect domain.
/etc/pam.d/login is not SELinux enabled
FSCKFIX is not enabled - not serious, but could prevent system from booting...
udev will create nodes not labeled correctly

Comment: Have you rebooted the machine after installing SELinux ?

Comment: May be this problem possible because in Debian Jessie there not exist a selinux-policy-default?

Answer (score 4):

This error might be because you are running AppArmor along with SELinux. AppArmor is installed by default in Ubuntu. You can't use 2 LSM (Linux security modules) at the same time. You need to remove AppArmor if you wish yo use SELinux

See an aswer here: [Is it a bad idea to run SELinux and AppArmor at the same time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23422/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-run-selinux-and-apparmor-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Thanks after I unstalled apparmor I was able to enable selinux and reboot my system. But now probelm, I downloaded the code from ref policy code from below site.
http://oss.tresys.com/projects/refpolicy/wiki/UseRefpolicy
And after I built policy code (as mentioned on site). I changed my config file to as below :

SELINUX=enforcing
SELINUXTYPE=refpolicy

Again I was not able to reboot my system.Please help

Comment: check-selinux-installation gives following error
getfilecon:  getfilecon(/proc/1) failed
SELinux is not enabled.
Could not read the domain of PID 1.
/etc/pam.d/login is not SELinux enabled
FSCKFIX is not enabled - not serious, but could prevent system from booting...
udev will create nodes not labeled correctly

Comment: Check sestatus if it returns enabled then it's working fine.

Also enter the command

grep FSC /etc/default/rcS 

If it returns #FSCKFIX=no then use gedit or any other editing tool to edit the rcS file uncomment the line and set it to yes (like this FSCKFIX=yes) then save and exit gedit. After editing the file re-enter the command grep FSC /etc/default/rcS should return FSCKFIX=yes

if the command check-selinux-installation returns just

/etc/pam.d/login is not SELinux enabled

then it's fine and the above return is a false positive.

Comment: FSCKFIX probelm is fixed.  now when I run check-selinux-installation command.  It gives following error.  
.. /proc/1 kernel...   
The init process (PID 1) is running in an incorrect domain.  
I am not able to enable SELINUX(I installed 3.9 kernel also).  
Please help.

Comment: There is one more probelm that /selinux folder is empty. How can I get it contents back as without it i can get my system booted once I enable SELINUX. Please help

Answer (score 2):

An absurdly old question, but it helped me track my problem down partially, so I'm adding another response.

Not only do you need to remove AppArmor like cioby23 says, but there are some extra steps received from the upstream Debian that aren't well documented at all.  Here are the commands to convert a standard Ubuntu system (16.04.6 for me) to use SELinux in Permissive mode using the standard provided packages:

```
# make sure you have the most up-to-date info
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade

#disable and remove apparmor
/etc/init.d/apparmor stop
apt-get remove apparmor

#install SELinux
apt-get install selinux

# install the missing dependency
apt-get install auditd

# install the activate tool required to make it work
apt-get install selinux-basics

#missing manual step to actually make SELinux work (part of selinux-basics)
selinux-activate

# need to restart for it to take effect
shutdown now
```

Personally I discovered that the `selinux-activate` has to be run manually from a discussion on the upstream Debian (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136988/whats-missing-with-my-selinux-installation).
It solved the exact problem of the wrong context on PID 1, which also presents as a `getfilecon` error.

**EDIT1**: Update language to avoid confusion on policy naming.
**EDIT2**: Split up the commands with better descriptions for each

Comment: Does selinux work ok on debian-based distros?
I tend to stick with the default MACs, but I'm not sure if this is only a prejudice or if there's actually some object reason behind it.
For instance here they say it is (still) experimental for Ubuntu:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-enable-selinux-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux