# Can't enable selinux on Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: configure, selinux

To start I'm a complete noobie in the matter of SElinux and ubuntu, so my problem is that I tried installing it on ubuntu server 18.04 using this tutorial: https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/install-selinux-on-ubuntu/

But I cannot enable it either using setenforce or changing config file in selinux.

```
root@test:/# setenforce 1
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
```

If you need more info, I will gladly provide them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a posting about SELinux at [https://askubuntu.com/questions/481293/selinux-implementation-in-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481293/selinux-implementation-in-ubuntu) which discusses installation

Comment: also worth reading: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/nl-NL/Fedora/11/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux.html

Comment: and also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/468821/selinux-is-not-enabled  We use apparmor and it will conflict with selinux

Comment: Thank you for your response
@CharlesGreen tried the steps from the link you posted, still selinux is disabled

Comment: @Rinzwind purged apparmor before installing SELinux, i believe i should use CentOS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just arrived here from a Google search.

Do *NOT* use SELinux with Ubuntu. It is not tested at all. After enabling SELinux, many package installations fail. In particular, anyone that runs "groupadd" to add a group specific to a service. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libselinux/+bug/1769301

SELinux is tested and enabled by default with CentOS and Redhat Enterprise Linux. Ubuntu offers AppArmor as alternative security mechanism. If you prefer SELinux, use a distribution that enables it by default, like Redhat or CentOS.

Comment: Thanks for your response !
I resoled my problem by installing CentOS after researching and finding that Ubuntu and SElinux aren't compatible at all.

Marked as ANSWER for other people with this kind of questions or ideas to see your info,

Have a great day !